# xampp is not installing in window 7

Tags: apache, xampp

I am trying to install xampp on my system. I am using window 7 32 bit. Whenever I run the setup i got the error in pop up that xampp has stopped working. I tried many version of xampp. After downloading the upgrade version of xampp setup 5.6.30 / PHP 5.6.30, 7.0.15 / PHP 7.0.15, 7.1.1 / PHP 7.1.1, i became able to install xampp which work only for one time, when i switch on my system again, apache and mysql did not start and give me an error that apache has stopped working. Please give me some solution how to solve that problem.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that you finally were able to install, but the services do not run after reboot?

Launch the Xampp control panel as administrator so that you can set the apache and mysql as services. (the first checkbox column, which is probably greyed-out, or not clickable, when the control panel is NOT run as administrator)

Those services will run after system reboot once those are set.